# I want AWS IAM USERS not to see each other services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-iam-policy

I have the following Json Code

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CreatedBy": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CreatedBy": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above code is I am viewing all the instances launched by other IAM users

I want to allow an IAM user to only view EC2 instances that they've launched while denying the ability to view instances launched by other IAM users.

is this possible ? can anyone help in altering this code ?

Comment: Its not possible to limit view permissions only to some instances. All users have to see all instances, or none.

Comment: I want the users to view Only the instances that they have launched @Marcin

Comment: @sai what you want is not possible

Comment: You could use sub accounts to isolate the resources from another

Comment: How can i do this ? can you please share the link if possible  @Tom

Answer (score 1):

According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) the `DescribeInstances` API call only accepts `ec2:Region` as a **Condition key**.

Therefore, if a user has permission to call `DescribeInstances` then they will see *all* EC2 instances. It is not possible to limit the response based on a tag or a property of the instance.

You would need to build your own method for returning a 'limited' set of responses. For example, they could call an AWS Lambda function that returns the list based on your own coded logic.